# ajax to retrieve data from another page after post

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I know this is very easy, but i only know the DOM equivalent of this code. the very long one. i've already searched trough some of the questions here in stack but i cant seem to find the solution.

so basically i have this script:

```
function searchNow(str)
{
    $.ajax({
    url: "search.php",
    type: "POST",
    async: false,
    data:  {"search": str},
    success: function(data){
            alert("test");
            $("#result").html(data);
        }
    });
}

<table>

<tr>
    <td>Search: </td>
    <td><input type = "text" name = "search" onBlur="searchNow(this.value)">      </td>
</tr>
```

this will submit search to search.php to do a query search and retrieve the result and display it at id result.

i can do this easily using the old DOM ajax but then i wanna try using this jquery version instead since it is cleaner and maybe faster.

at my search.php
i have this:

```
$search = $_POST['search'];
return $search;
```

sadly i cant seem to return anything at all.

some input would be greatly appreciated, im already starting to be familiar with jquery ajax but only on the same page, not on inter page manipulation.

thank you,
-magician

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your PHP file should output the value. The ajax is going read that page and get it's content.

```
$search = $_POST['search'];
echo $search;
```

Comment: put `console.log(arguments);` inside your success function and take a look in the javascript debug console (`cmd + opt + j` on a mac in chrome) to see what is happening. Is your `alert` firing?

Comment: the alert is not being triggered, it could be that success is not called at all. uhm im on windows.

Comment: it says $ is not defined after $.ajax

Comment: That means you have not included jquery on your page - or after your function declaring $.ajax

Comment: that solved it. no wonder i can't ever get this thing going, i need to use jquery library for it to work. i was so used to using the DOM one that it skipped me to include jquery. sorry about that. and thank you

Comment: I included the html you needed in my answer below, but you already had it. Glad it works :)

Answer (score 1):

You want to be doing `echo $search` rather than `return`.

You can also add `print_r($_POST);` to take a look at what is going on in the PHP side of things.

Once you see what that is doing you can develop your php script a little further.

```
// Sets the correct response type
header('Content-type: application/json');

// get your search string/query
$search = $_POST['search'];

/*
 * Do whatever you need in order to get a result
 */

echo json_encode($result);

exit;
```

If you are passing the search query to a database be sure to read Nettuts [great intro to PDO](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). There are a lot of common pitfalls that can lead to security issues/exploits - avoiding one of the main ones (SQL injection) is covered in that post.

As per your comment, make sure your page with the search field is properly including jquery in the right place (sorry I don't mean to patronise if this is obvious!)

```
<html>
<head>

    <title>Jquery Ajax</title>

    <!-- google nicely host jquery for free... -->
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    function searchNow(str)
    {
        $.ajax({
            url: "search.php",
            type: "POST",
            data:  { "search": str },

            success: function(data) {
                alert("test");
                $("#result").html(data);
            }
        });
    }
    </script>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Search: </td>
            <td><input type="text" name="search" onBlur="searchNow(this.value)" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <div id="results"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP file should output the value. The ajax is going read that page and get it's content.

```
$search = $_POST['search'];
echo $search;
```

Also, the success option is set to be deprecated in the future releases of jQuery. You should instead use .done(callbackFunction) like so:

```
    $.ajax({
      url: 'beh.php',
      type: 'POST',
      data: {search: "beeeeeeeh"}
    }).done(function () {
      // do stuff
    })
```

Also, is there any reason in particular why you are setting async to false?

Comment: are you passing data: {search: "behhhhhh"} in the $.ajax call? Also, post must be all caps, and passed as a string.

Answer (score 0):

Dont forget to create an HTML element with ID="result" used by the selector to contain the result printed by your search.php.

```
$("#result").html(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried using

```
type: 'GET'
```

and in php file, got the value as

```
$search = $_GET['search'];
echo $search;
```

It worked. Hope it works for you also.